# How to pass a column into a function?

Tags: function, powerbuilder, tablecolumn

I want to use columns in a function and the columns may differ from time to time. So I want to pass the columns into the function when calling the function, what datatype can be used in the function.

The following is the code that i want to put into the function and `compute_page` is the column name:

```
if dw_report.Object.compute_page[ll_first_row] <> dw_report.Object.compute_page[ll_last_row] then
```

Also, I want to do the same thing but this time is set the column value. I tried to use SetItem(), SetText(), SetValue(), but none of the function can achieve the expected result except using *dwcontrol*.Object.*columnname*[i] to set the value.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `.object` notation to access the column, use the `GetItemxxx()`, eg:

```
if dw_report.getitemnumber(ll_first_row, "compute_page") <> dw_report.getitemnumber(ll_last_row, "compute_page") then
```

Just replace the `"compute_page"` litteral in the example by a string argument of your function.

Beware that the `GetItemxx()` call must match the actual column data type, so you need to check for the result of `dw_report.describe(ls_your_column_name+".coltype")` to call one of `GetItemNumber()`, `GetItemString()`, `GetItemDecimal()`, `GetItemDate()`, `GetItemDatetime()` or your application will crash.

Comment: You'll also find the GetItemXXX() faster and more memory efficient than the .object. notation. It won't be a big deal if the script is called just once, but in a loop over a large data set, you'll notice the difference.

Comment: I Totally agree with @Terry, it seems that the `.object` notation is using an OLE layer to access the datawindow internals and tends to slow down the data process.

Comment: Thank you very much, but another similar question:

Comment: I want to set a value to a column in the same function, but it does not take effect when using SetItem(), SetColumn(), SetValue(). However, using the .object. notation is success. Any idea??  Thanks

Comment: @calvinyankf: do you get any return code or sql error message that could give some clue?

Comment: The problem was solved since the column and the value inside the SetItem() function are of different type. Thanks